# Using Swagger with WCF REST

Tags: wcf, rest, swagger

I have a WCF REST based service that I would like to add Swagger to.  I have installed Swagger.NET package, my project is using .NET 4.0.  I have also enabled XML documentation, etc... but now I am not sure the best route from here.

When i launch `http://localhost/SwaggerUI/index.html` I get the default page with the `http://YOUR-URL-HERE:PORT/api/swagger`.  I am not sure what url should go here.  I did enable help of the service via: `<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" />` which does give me the ugly page here:   `http://localhost/api/help` -- when i plug that into Swagger i just get the result:

```
200 : OK http://localhost/api/help
```

What is the best way to proceed, i am not using WebApi but have many of the features available if that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently there are no implementations of Swagger for WCF. You will either need to implement your own by following the spec from https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki, or wait patiently for someone to implement one for you.

I currently have an implementation in progress, but it's not quite ready for primetime. The basic spec is deceptively simple, but fitting it to WCF is a definite challenge.

Comment: Hey superstator, I don't suppose the implementation you have is ready for primetime yet?

Comment: We just published it, actually! I don't know about primetime, but it's available here: https://github.com/superstator/Swaggeratr

Comment: @superstator: the SampleService project folder is missing the swagger-ui/dist/...any clues on how to get the complete 'dist' folder contents?

Comment: @AdrianNasui You should just need to do a submodule update. I forget the exact commandline, though.

Comment: I got a new version of swagger-ui and placed it there, so got through that part. But still, when running swagger for the SampleService, I get an empty page containing only "[ base url:]". Any tips?

Comment: Basic troubleshooting is to check that you can query /api-docs and get some reasonable JSON back. If that works, you should just need to get swagger-ui pointed at that url. You may also need to verify that the swagger versions are compatible - I haven't looked at this in a while, and the latest swagger-ui may not understand the older swagger spec. If you still can't get it going, feel free to open a ticket over on github.

Answer (score 22):

As of December 2015, there is an implementation of Swagger for Wcf now. You should check this out - Swagger for WCF - [SwaggerWcf](https://libraries.io/nuget/SwaggerWcf)

Answer (score 5):

I tried to implement swagger for WCF in my application as the implementation is different as we implanted for web API(simpler). I will tell you how its different and how it works step by step:-

```
**1. Why Swagger4Wcf**
----------------------

•Manually writing yaml description for swagger and maintain it especially WCF services are boring. 
•There is a nuget package called Swagger4WCF that automatically generates yaml description for swagger 2.0 for each interface matching attributes used by WCF (ServiceContract/OperationContract/WebGet/WebInvoke).

2. How Swagger Works in the Background
--------------------------------------

Swagger4WCF uses NuPack post build pattern to trigger at build time.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1190360/How-to-setup-a-managed-postbuild-without-scripting
3.At build time, it will detect assemblies present in output directory, open them with mono.cecil (to reflect assemblies) to generate expected yaml description for swagger 2.0.
Swagger4WCF detects **WebGet/WebInvoke** to provide Verb/Method in serialization style in yaml.

Steps to implement Swagger in your application:-

1. Install SwaggerWcf package

2. Configure WCF routes
We have to add the route in the Application_Start method inside Global.asax

     protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("v1/rest", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(BookStore)));
                RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api-docs", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SwaggerWcfEndpoint)));
            }



Note: Edit Web.config and add the following (if it doesn't exist yet) inside the system.serviceModel block

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

3. Configure WCF response auto types (optional)
We have to add the following to Web.config. This will allow the WCF service to accept requests and send replies based on the Content-Type headers.






      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
              <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>



4. Decorate WCF services interfaces
For each method, we have to configure the WebInvoke or WebGet attribute, and add a SwaggerWcfPath attribute.



 [SwaggerWcfPath("Get book", "Retrieve a book from the store using its id")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/books/{id}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        Book ReadBook(string id);




5. Decorate WCF services class

•   Add the SwaggerWcf and AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attributes to the class providing the base path for the service.
•   For each method, add the SwaggerWcfTag to categorize the method and theSwaggerWcfResponse for each possible response from the service.



[SwaggerWcfTag("Books")]
[SwaggerWcfResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Book found, value in the response body")]
[SwaggerWcfResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "No books", true)]
public Book[] ReadBooks()
{
}



6. Decorate data types used in WCF services



 [DataContract]
    [Description("Book with title, first publish date, author and language")]
    [SwaggerWcfDefinition(ExternalDocsUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book", ExternalDocsDescription = "Description of a book")]
    public class Book
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Description("Book ID")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Description("Book Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Description("Book First Publish Date")]
        public int FirstPublished { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Description("Book Author")]
        public Author Author { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [Description("Book Language")]
        public Language Language { get; set; }
    }

 That's it wcf for Swagger implemented.
Please free if you face any issue.

Thanks,
Abhi
```

Comment: I just implemented the swagger in wcf using SwaggerWcf (nuget package) by AbeSilva. the latest version of the nugget package is currently not working instead of that we can try out version 0.1.23.  (install-package swaggerwcf -version 0.1.23)

Comment: can you share the way you integrated i need it too

Comment: i have already shared the steps in the above example.Please go step by step and you will be able to achieve. please reach out for any clarification.

Comment: there are so many version updates from 0.1.23, how come you went back that far? the others don't work either? i agree i tried the latest which is 0.2.15 and it did not work for me.

Comment: I have already mentioned that the latest version are not working so stick with the version which is working fine.

Comment: at which end point can I see the swagger documentation as in the above example you have not configured any endpoints?